# Pyspark EMR "The connection attempt failed" when i try to save a datafreme in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

When I try to save a dataframe in Postgres using pyspark on EMR I get the following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

However the table is created, but without the data.

```
df.write.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/dbtest")
.option("dbtable", "table_example")
.option("user","user")
.option("password", "pass").option("driver","org.postgresql.Driver" ).save()
```

Result in postgre:

```
            List of relations
 Schema |     Name      | Type  |  Owner
--------+---------------+-------+----------
 public | table_example | table | user

select * from table_example;

 age | name
-----+------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: check the firewall settings of postgres.

Comment: It's strange, because when I connect to postgres  using libraries like psycopg2 it works fine

Comment: @Bar did you figure this out? i'm stuck on this as well.